# Changing BorderLayout in Java Swing for more appealing UI

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, layout-manager, jcheckbox

I would like to change my current layout to a new one, more advanced, but I have some issues with it. The current layout is as this:
[image]

All the displayed elements are in a panel (bottom panel, there is a top one which just includes `JTable` but is not relevant in this case) the checkboxes are in a `JScrollPaneBox`, which border layout is
`BorderLayout.CENTER`, then the buttons are in a `Box` and added to the panel with border layout `BorderLayout.EAST`, and the search field is added to the panel with borderlayout `BorderLayout.SOUTH`
But this layout is especially 'ugly' when the app is on fullscreen.
[image]

I would like to have a layout like this: **https://wireframe.cc/Kb05km**

How can I add the two labels and add a space between checkboxes and search field? Also how can I limit the maximum width of checkboxes' `ScrollPaneBox` and the search field?
Thanks!

Comment: *I would like to have a layout like this* - and what is the problem? Looks like a scroll pane is added to the CENTER. Then another panel is added to the PAGE_END. This second panel can also contain nested panels with different layout managers to achieve your layout. *Also how can I limit the maximum width of checkboxes' ScrollPaneBox and the search field?* - it is controlled by the layout manager. Read the Swing tutorial on [Layout Managers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) for the basics of each layout manager and working examples.

Comment: *"I would like to have a layout like this:"* Is the GUI resizable? If so, how should the extra width and height be assigned? Note that most good layouts result from combining layout managers - each specific to a section of the overall GUI.

Comment: the problem is asked in the last sentence, i.e. how can I add a space between elements (search field and scroll pane), and how can I limit it's width?

Comment: Space around elements depends on which Swing layout we're talking about.  The FlowLayout, BoxLatout, BorderLayout, GridLaypout, and GridBagLayouit all have parameters or methods for putting space around Swing elements.

Comment: *"How can I add the two labels and add a space between checkboxes and search field?"* Layout padding or an `EmptyBorder` is what I'd usually use for that. *"how can I limit it's width?"* I'd usually put the component in a `FlowLayout`. That will try to assign a component its preferred size, and won't stretch it to fill the container.

Comment: For more info on what @GilbertLeBlanc & I suggested re white space, see [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17874717/providing-white-space-in-a-swing-gui).